# apt-get install bluez only installing documentation

Tags: python, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

I've been struggling for the past two days to get my Bluetooth keyboard to work with my Raspberry Pi 2, with Kali 2.0 installed (I have gotten Adafruit's PiTFT software from http://adafruit-download.s3.amazonaws.com/adafruit_pitft_kernel_1.20150420-1.tar.gz, and have installed it, and it's helper script). I'm thinking this is a software issue, since my Bluetooth dongle is recognized with `hcitool dev`, and I can properly scan nearby Bluetooth devices with `hcitool scan`.

I followed an article, that said to install several things (to get the Bluetooth to work), one of which was `bluez-utils`. Apt returned an error, saying that `bluez-utils` was outdated, and `bluez` was a replacement for it. So I removed `bluez-utils` from the command, and installed `bluez`, `python-gobject`, and a few other needed packages. Then, I tried using `bluez`, to find that I got command not found from bash. So, I did a filesystem search with `find /* | grep bluez` to find that bluez's documentation was installed, but `bluez` wasn't. I then tried installing it from source, to find that it needed a ton of dependencies, and those dependencies needed tons of dependencies, etc., so I gave up on that route.

I would be fine installing `bluez` from source, if there is a *simple* and *easy* way to do it.

Any help with installing bluez would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bluez` package doesn't install a `bluez` binary, so it's perfectly normal that your shell can't find one; it installs the `bluetoothd` daemon and a number of different tools, `bccmd`, `bluemoon`, `bluetoothctl`, `btmon`, `ciptool`, `gatttool`, `hciattach`, `hcitool`, `hex2hcd`, `l2ping`, `l2test`, `mpris-proxy`, `rctest`, `rfcomm` and `sdptool`, along with manpages which explain how to use them.

To see what was installed, run `dpkg -L bluez`.

Comment: This was in part of what my issue was. I ended up installing it from source, and used `bluetoothctl`.

Comment: I was wondering where `bluez-simple-agent` was, because an article I read used it, and it wasn't included in `bluez`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this (worked for me) is to reinstall the program. When uninstalling, completely uninstall it instead of normally. Then install it as you would normally.

Also, it might help to read the documentation that it installed!

Comment: I tried this twice, and it didn't work. I also tried uninstalling it with `apt-get purge`, and it still didn't work. I ended up installing it from source, from an article, and got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following http://www.elinux.org/RPi_Bluetooth_LE, and it worked fine. Thanks for all of your help!

Also, I believe my issue was that `bluez` didn't install a binary called `bluez`, it installed other tools.